# Why was my retag rejected?

Tags: discussion, tagging, editing, retagging

A couple of days ago I was looking for algebraic geometry questions to answer and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689297/conjecture-about-crossing-paths-in-n-times-n-grid-counterexample-or-ideas) appeared in my feed. It has nothing to do with algebraic geometry, so I wanted to remove that tag in order to make it better reflect what the question is actually about.

The [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1391335) was rejected because

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

While I agree that my edit wasn't substantial, I believe that it does make the question **more accurate** and it does make relevant posts **easier to find**.

This belief is based on the facts that the algebraic geometry tag specifically says:

> This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry.

The other belief is based on the fact that I would never have clicked on this question if it was appropriately tagged.

Comment: I think you were correct in pushing for the tag to be removed, and it has been removed now.

Comment: I agree that the rejection was unwarranted and have removed the tag. Unfortunately, I didn't think to check whether I could override the rejection before I did that.

Comment: When you suggest an edit, there's a place for describing the edit you're suggesting. Did you write in that place that you were suggesting the removal of an inappropriate tag, David?

Comment: I did, yes, my comment was: "Removed inappropriate tag". Thanks everyone, it seems as if this was just a mistake.

Comment: It is an unavoidable side effect of the way the site works that users who have done calculus homework for a number of askers are deemed qualified to judge things like this. Hang in there. After you get the appropriate privilege, your edits will no longer be "reviewed" by such people.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proposal was fine. By now a moderator changed the tag. Also note that there was one positive review too. (It was declined 2 vs 1.)

It's hard to know what exactly happened. Maybe the reviewers disagreed that changing the tag is relevant enough for an edit (in my opinion, it is, at least in clear cases like this). Or maybe they did not realize that changing the tag was the point.